# What is this manga about a high school class that turns into a kingdom?

Tags: oukoku-game

It starts with a group of high schoolers in a room being made into a kingdom, where each day a new king or queen is chosen, along with two nobles and the rest as commoners, the nobles and commoners have to obey all that the king or queen of the days demands, commoners also have to obey the nobles.

Does anyone know what this manga is?

Comment: I upvoted your question because I didn't think the downvote was necessary, but could you please add a bit more detail to your question. (if you can) :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is [**Oukoku Game**](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=95782).

[image: Volume 1 Cover]

Synopsis from mangaupdates (emphasis mine):

> At the end of Meiji Restoration, a girl saint was crucified and burnt alive under persecution.
>
> A century later, Katori and six childhood friends are summoned to her world beyond the nirvana, where they receive the Great Commission: Build a kingdom, and make disciples of all nations.
>
> **At every midnight, each of them are randomly given a role out of King/Queen, Noble, and Peasants**. As the lowly must obey a higher-up in the hierarchy, can they fight and defeat other nations to conquer the world--before infighting brought up by their own hidden desires breaks them apart?